# Block Completion no longer works after update to Windows 10

Tags: settings, c++builder

I recently updated to Windows 10. Since doing that, RAD no longer automatically completes blocks for me. If I type an open bracket then press enter, it used to indent the next line and put a closing bracket on the line after that.

Here is what my settings look like:
[image]

Is there a way to re-enable this feature?

Comment: Have you filed a bug report in [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com) yet? Have you checked to make sure all relevant .NET dependencies that the IDE uses are installed properly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, I haven't filed a bug report. I didn't realize there was a quality portal, thanks for pointing that out. I'll submit a report now.

How do I check what .NET dependencies it uses?